# Don't treat rows separately and don't include table-metadata

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

If I have a table of this form:

```
  Setting      Value    
 ---------- ----------- 
  Setting1   Value1     
  Test       TestValue  
  Etc        EtcVal
```

And query the data with this SQL-Code:

```
SELECT `Setting`, `Value` FROM Settings
```

How can I obtain a result array of this form:

```
Array ( [Setting1] => Value1, [Test] => TestValue, [Etc] => EtcVal )
```

Currently the array I get from the request looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ([Setting] => Setting1, [Value] => Value1), [1] => Array ([Setting] => Test, [Value] => TestValue), etc )
```

And I really don't want this...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the solution was quite simple.
I just needed to iterate over all entries in the table, and associate the entries value with it's setting-name.

```
$arr = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $arr[$row['Setting']] = $row['Value'];
}
```